# Why is the expected number of steps to finish this game $O(n^2)$?

Tags: probability

Say I play a game. I start at a number line at 0. At each step, I increment by 1 with probability 1/2 and decrement by 1 with probability 1/2. The game ends when I am at integer $n$.

Why do I take an expected $O(n^2)$ number of steps to finish the game? The game seems to hark to a geometric series, but I can go in both directions ...

Comment: The game that you describe needs, on average, an infinite number of steps to finish.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I'm familiar with the analogous result for Brownian motions and how to show it using Dynkin's formula. Reference on how to show it in the discrete setting?

Comment: Oh, why does it take an infinite number of steps?

Comment: @DavidFaux Imagine a single boundary point at $n=1$. Then first step analysis shows that the expected time $e$  to hit the boundary satisfies $e=1+e^2/2$. There is no real solution, so $e=\infty$.